# I need help to establish a variable without binding in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, variables

I need help to establish a variable without binding in angular 2.
The model comes from a JSON and there are null and full fields.
I'm trying this:

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" [ngClass]="rowData[col.field] !=null ? 'original' : 'empty'">
```

but when you change the value of a null field angular set "original" class 
and i lost the trazability
Best regards

Comment: Can you elaborate better the question? It's not clear to me the current scenario and what you do expect instead

Comment: I try to generate a XML kwnoing the values are changed

Comment: Can you try this `<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" [ngClass]="rowData[col.field] ? 'original' : 'empty'">`

Comment: You could make use of `ReactiveFormsModule` and take `.value` of `FormGroup` thus having a regular object

Comment: @KunalMukherjee when i type in a empty input the class be changed to "original"... but thanks